# Netmq crash after receiving publication

Tags: python, pyzmq, netmq

We are doing a ZMQ PUB/SUB method. Where the PUB/SUB exchange is written in dot net (.Net) and a publisher to the .Net exchange is written in Python. 
When the Python PUB's to the .Net exchange it often crashes, with the following error:

```
mono phoenix.exe XChange                                                                    

[73/73]Phoenix v.1.1.16.32 {DEBUG}
Command:XCHANGE 
Starting XChange: PhoenixExchange[XSubAddr:tcp://*:5201[In] XPubAddr:tcp://*:5202[In]]

Unhandled Exception:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: count
  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.SetBufferInternal (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) <0x7423bc20 + 0x000e4> in <filename unkn
own>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.SetBuffer (Int32 offset, Int32 count) <0x7423d278 + 0x00027> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at AsyncIO.DotNet.NativeSocket.Receive (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, SocketFlags flags) <0x7423c8b0 + 0x000f3> in <filename unknown
>:0 
  at NetMQ.Core.Transports.StreamEngine.BeginRead (NetMQ.Core.Transports.ByteArraySegment data, Int32 size) <0x7423c7d0 + 0x00057> in <filename unknown>:
0 
  at NetMQ.Core.Transports.StreamEngine.HandleHandshake (Action action, SocketError socketError, Int32 bytesTransferred) <0x742399b0 + 0x007df> in <filen
ame unknown>:0 
  at NetMQ.Core.Transports.StreamEngine.Handle (Action action, SocketError socketError, Int32 bytesTransferred) <0x74238b78 + 0x0019b> in <filename unkno
wn>:0 
  at NetMQ.Core.Transports.StreamEngine.FeedAction (Action action, SocketError socketError, Int32 bytesTransferred) <0x742387c8 + 0x0002b> in <filename u
nknown>:0 
  at NetMQ.Core.Transports.StreamEngine.InCompleted (SocketError socketError, Int32 bytesTransferred) <0x7423d188 + 0x00027> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NetMQ.Core.IOObject.InCompleted (SocketError socketError, Int32 bytesTransferred) <0x74236408 + 0x0003b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NetMQ.Core.Utils.Proactor.Loop () <0x74218f88 + 0x00343> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (System.Object state) <0x748a8100 + 0x000c7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System
.Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) <0x748a67bc + 0x001af> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object 
state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) <0x748a6788 + 0x0002b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object 
state) <0x748a66e4 + 0x0005b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart () <0x748a82d0 + 0x00037> in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: count
  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.SetBufferInternal (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) <0x7423bc20 + 0x000e4> in <filename unkn
own>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.SetBuffer (Int32 offset, Int32 count) <0x7423d278 + 0x00027> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at AsyncIO.DotNet.NativeSocket.Receive (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, SocketFlags flags) <0x7423c8b0 + 0x000f3> in <filename unknown
>:0 
  at NetMQ.Core.Transports.StreamEngine.BeginRead (NetMQ.Core.Transports.ByteArraySegment data, Int32 size) <0x7423c7d0 + 0x00057> in <filename unknown>:
0 
  at NetMQ.Core.Transports.StreamEngine.HandleHandshake (Action action, SocketError socketError, Int32 bytesTransferred) <0x742399b0 + 0x007df> in <filen
ame unknown>:0 
  at NetMQ.Core.Transports.StreamEngine.Handle (Action action, SocketError socketError, Int32 bytesTransferred) <0x74238b78 + 0x0019b> in <filename unkno
wn>:0 
  at NetMQ.Core.Transports.StreamEngine.FeedAction (Action action, SocketError socketError, Int32 bytesTransferred) <0x742387c8 + 0x0002b> in <filename u
nknown>:0 
  at NetMQ.Core.Transports.StreamEngine.InCompleted (SocketError socketError, Int32 bytesTransferred) <0x7423d188 + 0x00027> in <filename unknown>:0
```

The python code is a simple pub.

```
import sys, os
is_py2 = sys.version[0] == '2'

import time, datetime
import zmq 
from xml.etree import ElementTree as xmltree


def publishpageforoledtoxchange():
    """
    publishpageforoledtoxchange - this is to test the OLEDS.PY
    It will send a couple pages to the oled.
    :return:
    """
    try:
        pub = "tcp://%s:%s" % ("172.16.0.10", "5201")
        context = zmq.Context()
        sock_outbound = context.socket(zmq.PUB)  # PUSH
        sock_outbound.linger = 0
        try:
            sock_outbound.bind(pub)
            print("Outbound publisher bind succesfull = %s" % (pub,))
            time.sleep(1)
        except:
            sock_outbound = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
            sock_outbound.connect(pub)
            print("Outbound publisher connect succesfull = %s" % (pub,))
            time.sleep(1)


        #     Topic: OLED.Display. < option > page name / guid
        #     < xmOLEDPage Page = "TestPage" TTL = "60" TStamp = "iso format" >
        #     < RenderText Size = "1" X = "1" Y = "1" Text = "Hello World" / >
        # < / xmOLEDPage >
        systree = xmltree.Element("xmOLEDPage")
        systree.attrib['Page'] = '%s' % "Pub1"
        systree.attrib['TTL'] = "900"
        systree.attrib['TStamp'] = "%s" %datetime.datetime.now()
        renderelm = xmltree.SubElement(systree, "RenderText")
        renderelm.attrib['X'] = "0"
        renderelm.attrib['Y'] = "0"
        renderelm.attrib['Text'] = "012345678901234567890"
        renderelm2 = xmltree.SubElement(systree, "RenderText")
        renderelm2.attrib['X'] = "0"
        renderelm2.attrib['Y'] = "13"
        renderelm2.attrib['Text'] = "Y13 45678901234567890"
        renderelm3 = xmltree.SubElement(systree, "RenderText")
        renderelm3.attrib['X'] = "0"
        renderelm3.attrib['Y'] = "30"
        renderelm3.attrib['Text'] = "Y30 4  YES  890"

        xmlstr = xmltree.tostring(systree, method='xml')
        print(xmlstr)

        sendmsg1  = ["OLED.Display.Test", xmlstr]
        sock_outbound.send_multipart(sendmsg1)
        time.sleep(2)


        for x in range(0, 99):
            sock_outbound.send_multipart(sendmsg1)
            time.sleep(4)


    except Exception as exct:
        print("Outbound exct = %s" % (exct,))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        publishpageforoledtoxchange()
    except Exception as mainerr:
        print("Main execption occured: %s" %mainerr)
    os._exit(-1)
```

Comment: It looks like a socket is closed unexpectedly and you do `os._exit(-1)` at the end, skipping normal python shutdown (incluing no wait for background threads). Not sure if its related but it does seem odd. Does your python script close in all of this? And why not just `exit(-1)` and why an error return even if everything works?

Comment: I'll try removing the os_exit()

Comment: removed the bind from python - only calling connect - seem to have fixed the problem - thanks